# Read the time frame in the file line by line and assign to a variable in nodejs

Tags: node.js, regex

I have a file which has values

```
Start : Wed Dec 18 2019 09:55:15 GMT+0530 (IST) 
End : Wed Dec 18 2019 10:11:23 GMT+0530 (IST) 
Duration : 00:16:07.278
```

So I need to get the values coming after

> Start :
>
> End :
>
> Duration :

and assign to 3 variables.

Please let me know how we can try that in nodejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can parse the date as is with `new Date(date string from your file)`...
so just split the file into single lines and then remove the starting `Start :` etc...

as for the Duration, you can split on ":" and then turn the hours and minutes into seconds adding all together in the end...

```js
var st = `Start : Wed Dec 18 2019 09:55:15 GMT+0530 (IST) 
End : Wed Dec 18 2019 10:11:23 GMT+0530 (IST) 
Duration : 00:16:07.278 `

var lines = st.split("\n")

var start = new Date(lines[0].split("Start :")[1])
var end = new Date(lines[1].split("End :")[1])

var a_dur = lines[2].replace("Duration :", "").split(":")
var dur = Number(a_dur[0]) * 60 * 60 + Number(a_dur[1]) * 60 + Number(a_dur[2])

e_start.innerHTML = start
e_end.innerHTML = end
e_duration.innerHTML = dur
```

```html
Start:
<div id="e_start"></div><br/> End:
<div id="e_end"></div><br/> Duration:
<div id="e_duration"></div><br/>
```